# Evaluation of $\int\frac{x}{\ln(x)} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus

I know that when you integrate $\frac x {\ln{ x}}$, you get an answer in terms of the exponential function? I was just wondering how would one begin doing this. I tried integrating by parts, but the integration soon began to repeat.

Comment: Here is an answer in terms of the upper incomplete gamma function $-\Gamma(0,-2\ln(x))$.

Comment: There is no answer in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u=\ln x$ so $\mathrm d u= \mathrm d x / x$. Then we end up integrating
$$(x/\ln x) \mathrm d x = (e^{2u}/u) \mathrm d u$$
Considering the definition of the exponential integral http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral with $v=2u$ gives the answer.

*Note*: This function does not have an elementary expression involving only familiar functions and rational functions. In particular the function $\mathrm{Ei}$ is not the "exponential function".

Answer (score 2):

Use $u$ substitution.

$$\int\frac{x}{\ln(x)}dx=\int\frac{2x}{2\ln(x)}dx=\int\frac{2x}{\ln(x^2)}dx$$

$$u=x^2$$

$$\int\frac{1}{\ln(u)}du=li(u)+C$$

Therefore

$$\int\frac{x}{\ln(x)}dx=li(x^2)+C$$

Where $li(u)$ is the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this is equivalent to my answer via $\hbox{li}(y)=\hbox{Ei}(\ln y)$.

Comment: @Sharkos Yes. Different algebra, same calculus :)